Power washer malfunction - dangerous? And how to fix?
I have a CleanForce 1400 that’s about 12 years old. I haven’t used it in a few years. I went to blast some dirty trash bins and mossy patio tiles, but while it was blasting pretty strong, it seemed weaker than I remembered. Then I realized it was leaking water out of the top of the soap dispenser bottle. Not just a little, but flowing. When I recap the soap dispenser, the cap comes right back off, with pressure. Boof! And keeps flowing.
I found the manual online, but nothing resembling this contingency is covered in the instructions or troubleshooting. As it reads, I don’t think the water is even supposed to be routing through the soap bottle when the gun is in the high pressure setting, which I double-checked it is. I tried switching back and forth between the low and high pressure setting (tip of the gun), but the soap bottle leaks both ways.
I have 2 questions:

Is this a risk for electrocution? Water is flowing straight down on the vertical unit. I turned off the water at the spigot and unplugged the machine without killing myself, but I’m wondering how worried I should be, if I attempt to use it again.

Can I fix it?



This is a good place for a GFCI.  Check the cap to see if it is vented type.

Plastic is a good insulator unless it is wet.

Your unit comes with a GFCI plug that should give you additional, good protection against being shocked or electrocuted if it is working correctly. Check to make sure it is operating correctly by pressing the "test" and "reset" buttons.
You're right about the soap bottle not being connected to the high pressure side. My guess is that a gasket or seal has deteriorated and high pressure water is leaking out of the chamber. You might still be able to get parts for it but disassembling it will be a challange because most of the screws will be rusted and hard to remove without twisting off the heads (ask me how I know .. :-)). You'll need to remove all of the plastic housings and then determine exactly where it's leaking from and then check for parts.

Thanks for your reply. It’s been stashed in my air conditioned basement, so maybe it didn’t rust too bad? It doesn’t sound like a quick fix, in any case - so that is helpful to know. I will take it apart if I can. Thanks again!
